# azure custom extension script passing az cli to bash script

Tags: bash, azure, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to pass parameters from arm template custom script extension to bash script 
az login -u azUsername -p azPassword

I am not sure how to pass these values to sh script and its getting keep on failing

```
"commandToExecute": {
                    "value": "[concat('sh samplebash.sh',' ',parameters('azUsername'),' ',parameters('azPassword'))]"
                }
```

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$azUsername"
echo "${azUsername}"
echo azUsername
echo $azUsername
echo hello
```

Need some help to get the values in bash script
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't any update, so what is the situation now? Do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to set the `commandToExecute` like this:

```
"executeCommand": "[concat('sh samplebash.sh', ' ', parameters('azUsername'), ' ', parameters('azPassword'))]"
```

Then you can set the extension like this:

```
"commandToExecute": "[variables('executeCommand')]"
```

Or you can set the extension directly like this:

```
"commandToExecute": "[concat('sh samplebash.sh', ' ', parameters('azUsername'), ' ', parameters('azPassword'))]"
```

And in the script, you should do some changes, there are two ways.

**First:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "azUsername:$1"
echo "azPassword:$2"
```

**Second:**

```
#!/bin/bash

azUsername=$1
azPassword=$2
echo $azUsername
echo $azPassword
```

By the way, I think when you use the `#!/bin/bash` in the script, then you'd better execute the script with the command `bash script.sh`. In some Linux distribution, `sh` is not the same command as `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I didn't know the first method exists, but I didnt get answer right in second method because of using space in between variable and argument. Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.